# create IE add-on using .net

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

I want to know how can i develop an addon for IE8+ which will convert some particular texts into hyperlinks, in the page shown in the current IE window, uisng C#.

I have gone through the reply's given over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840803/ie-addon-development-in-net), but I want to use an open source api or any code walk through will help.

Comment: Don't. First of all, you'll kill performance, as your extension will have to start up .NET each time a new tab (or, less intrusive, a new window) is opened. On common extensions written in .NET this amounts to roughly a second of loading time upon opening a new tab. Then this is a game not two extensions can play safely at once, as only one version of .NET can be loaded in a process. In short: don't, use C++.

Comment: @Joey - I am .net developer, is there any other way to develop this, other than using c++ ?

Comment: Any other compiled language that interfaces with COM and does *not* bring its own giant framework that's loaded only once per process. Delphi might be an option.

Comment: You shouldn't pretend every problem is a nail just because you only know how to use a hammer.  Some solutions just shouldn't be done in a managed language (even if it's technically possible to do so).  IE and Windows Explorer extensions are examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an add-on using Addin Express (.NET), but your IE instance will be slow.
http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/index.php

I'd recommend writing the add-in with C++.

Take a look here:
http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp

Or here if you aren't as familiar with COM:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SpicIE

Comment: I have used SpicIE, for it. Although the answer came in late, but still I appreciate it. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: I found an easier way.  Just install the "IE Tab" in Google Chrome and just develop your own Google Chrome extension.  You can set the "IE Tab" to any IE version you want in Windows as long as you have the version (or anything later) installed in Windows.  It's a piece of cake.  You just have to know JSON and understand the chrome extension JavaScript library.

Comment: I will surely take a look at that. Thanks :)